# how i can add a id in js on click event

Tags: javascript, css

Hey all i am new in java script so please help me out

i have a `input`tag so what i want is when some body click on `input` tag so the `#helptext` will call automatically by **js**.

how i can achieve this below the demo code and desired result image....

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tn98m/7/)

i want like this image :- [image]

**please check my updated DEMO bit of change in my markup i need like my current demo**

Comment: use .onClick() function

Comment: What is `#helptext` element? Should it be created dynamically? What tag should it correspond?

Comment: Do you want to add an id `#helptext` to input itself?

Comment: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/tn98m/2/) with jQuery.

Comment: @Shailender ji if you have chose class than is very easy chcek to demo http://jsfiddle.net/tn98m/8/

Comment: rohit please check my image what exactly i need..... i tested with css but its not working....

Comment: @ShailenderArora My fri Please check to this demo http://jsfiddle.net/tn98m/20/ now you can change some html part ...

Comment: rohit please check my image what exactly i need..... i tested with css but its not working....is it any gud way to add any class or id onclick if somebody will click on input tag so the required class or id should call....

Comment: @RohitAzad we can't check the markup the problem is this.....

Comment: See my answer .. I think its one of the way .. Better apply CSS in onClick for the input tag

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        $(this).append(event.target.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $('#helptext').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tn98m/9/

```
$('#myInput').focus(function() {
  $('#helptext').show();
});

$('#myInput').blur(function() {
  $('#helptext').hide();
});
```